# print N line after the pattern till blank line is reached

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I need to print multiple lines after the pattern is hit till the blank line is reached.

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd

aaa
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
jjj
```

Desired output with group data in one line:

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd 
aaa fff ggg hhh iii jjj
```

Comment: Why someone down vote a question without telling why, hmm. So I gave it an up vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$1=$1' RS="\n\n" file
aaa bbb ccc ddd
aaa fff ggg hhh iii jjj
```

Or some more robust (in case of a `0` as first digit.

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' RS="\n\n" file
```

PS, this may only work with gawk, or awk that supports multiple characters in RS

Answer (score 1):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1}1' RS= FS='\n' OFS=' ' file
aa bbb ccc ddd
aaa fff ggg hhh iii jjj
```

Comment: @user2809888 np, the benefit of using `OFS` is that you can easily change the format of the data, for example for CSV just set `OFS=,`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/(.)\n/\1 /g' inputfile
aaa bbb ccc ddd 
aaa fff ggg hhh iii jjj
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\n$//;t;s/\n/ /;ta' file
```